# How to deal with big float numbers in python

Tags: python-2.7, int, floating-accuracy

Some part of my code generates  big int number, which is further used in other calculations.This number is generated by calling factorial function . Since in other calculation , float numbers and a big int is involved ,so I am getting an error saying

> "OverflowError: long int too large to convert to float".

Is there anyway to work around this limitation ?
Here I am attaching my code .

```
import numpy as np
    #=============================alpha
def alpha(li,dtype=float):
    ai=1.0
    for mi in range(1,li+1):
        ai=ai*(1-(1/(2.0*mi)))
    return ai
def gamma(li,dtype=int):
    return  np.power(np.exp(1)/li,li)*(np.math.factorial((li)))

def J1J2(xi,deltai,dtype=int):
    xii=np.abs(xi)
    j1i=np.power(np.abs(xii-deltai),2.0)
    j2i=np.power(np.abs(xii+deltai),2.0)
    return int(np.floor(j1i)),int(np.ceil(j2i))
#========================***********
def R(Xi,sigmai,ni,dtype=float):
    ui=Xi/sigmai

    a1i=np.power(np.exp(1)/ni,ni)
    a2i=np.power(ui,2.0*ni)
    a3i=(np.power(ui,2.0))
    a4i=np.exp(-a3i)
    ri=a1i*a2i*a4i    
    return ri

def R1(Xi,sigmai,ni,dtype=float):
    ui=1.0*Xi/sigmai
    ri=np.exp(-2.0*np.power(ui-np.sqrt(ni),2.0))    
    return  ri    

def Sumpro(xi,ni,sigmai,a1i,a2i,dtype=float):
    Sum=0.0
    for li in (a1i,a2i):
        Sum=Sum+(alpha(li)/gamma(np.abs(ni-li)))*R(xi,sigmai,np.abs(ni-li))
    return 2.0*gamma(ni)*Sum

def Xmatrix(Xi,sigmai,Kxi,Nxi,deltai,dtype=float):
    Xmati=np.zeros((Kxi,Nxi),dtype=float)
    for i in range(Nxi):
        xi=1.0*Xi[i]
        ui=xi/sigmai
        J1i,J2i=J1J2(ui,deltai)
        print(i,' ',J1i,J2i)
        Xmati[0:J1i,i]=1
        for j in range(J1i,J2i):
            print(j )
            Xmati[j,i]=Sumpro(xi,j,sigmai,np.abs(J1i),np.abs(j))
    return Xmati    


def Xmatrix1(Xi,sigmai,Kxi,Nxi,deltai,dtype=float):
    Xmati=np.zeros((Kxi,Nxi),dtype=float)
    for i in range(Nxi):
        xi=1.0*Xi[i]
        ui=xi/sigmai
        ni=int(np.floor(np.sqrt(np.abs(ui))))
        J1i,J2i=J1J2(ui,deltai)
        Xmati[ni,i]=Sumpro(xi,ni,sigmai,np.abs(J1i),np.abs(ni))

    return Xmati    

x=np.linspace(10.0,100.0,50)
X=Xmatrix1(x,1,100,50,np.exp(-1.05))
```

Comment: The easiest work around is to truncate your large int. But I don't think that's what you want. Have you considered splitting your number into a large int component and a large float component?

Comment: If I understand you correctly , What you are saying is should I consider large factorial and float no separately ? .But my question is "is there any method by which  while doing numerical calculations involving large int and  float ,I don't face overflow problem ?" . Truncation is out of question. Thank you for your reply .

Comment: For my calculations, It's okay if I do work only with integer output . So what I want is to remove all floating numbers out of my calculations . Is it possible ?

Comment: Try http://mpmath.org/ arbitrary precision floating point. Or if you are going to work with large integers only, try https://gmpy2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/mpz.html#

Comment: try the bigfloat package of numpy

Answer (score 1):

The integer number size in python are infinite in theory and actually limited to the memory but floating point numbers are limited. You can check the limitation of floating point numbers in python by this code:

```
In [1]: import sys
In [2]: sys.float_info
Out[3]: sys.float_info(max=1.7976931348623157e+308, max_exp=1024, max_10_exp=308, min=2.2250738585072014e-308, min_exp=-1021, min_10_exp=-307, dig=15, mant_dig=53, epsilon=2.220446049250313e-16, radix=2, rounds=1)
```

Solution: You can use some external libraries to manage huge floating-point-numbers such as: [bigfloat](https://pypi.org/project/bigfloat/)